# Increase Android Emulator GREF

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

When I am running my Xamarin.Android application on emulator it is crushed when GREF has increased to 2001 :

```
07-10 13:08:12.113 D/dalvikvm( 2154): GREF has increased to 2001
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154): JNI global reference table (0xb9059ae0) dump:
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):   Last 10 entries (of 2001):
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      2000: 0xab294a58 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1999: 0xab2949f8 mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1998: 0xab294828 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1997: 0xab294458 android.widget.ImageView
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1996: 0xab294320 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1995: 0xab2942c0 mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1994: 0xab293cc8 android.widget.TextView
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1993: 0xab293658 android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1992: 0xab290998 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):      1991: 0xab290860 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-10 13:08:12.113 W/dalvikvm( 2154):   Summary:
```

On Android device it works well.
Is there the way to get rid from GREF or increase GREF number before Android application on emulator gonna crush?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulators have a limited GREF count. The count is ~2000. **You are reaching that limit.** Your best course of action here is to just test on an actual device as they have a much higher GREF count (~52000).

Although there's not a great way to increase this, you can potentially try the following property:

`adb shell setprop debug.mono.max_grefc <integer value>`

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/#debug.mono.maxgrefc

However my advice regarding running on a device is the ideal situation here.

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet got to a full analysis of the behavior you are seeing - without a full sample of your code it is very hard to do.

**The general case for bound lists is that the GREFs are incremented:**

- once for every ListView item - because that is used in the list
- once for every View object within the ListView which has a bound
  property or event - e.g. if you are binding to a TextView and a
  Button within each ListView item, then the C# will store references
  to these views

You can refer this link for help

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/568/when-to-release-dispose-java-objects-jni-gref-question#latest